# why does my code "break" out of loop?

Tags: python

```
fileName = raw_input("Enter the filename: ")
n = input("Enter the line you want to look: ")
f = open(fileName,'r')
numbers = []

for line in f:
    sentenceInLine = line.split('\n')
    for word in sentenceInLine:
          if word != '':
              numbers.append(word)
print numbers
print len(numbers)
print numbers[n-1]

if n == 0:
    print "There is no 0 line"
    break
```

Comment: The original question require when user input n = 0, the program quits.

Answer (score 2):

i think you missed to split `sentenceInLine` like `sentenceInLine.split(' ')`

Answer (score 2):

You are looping over each line, then you split lines based on `'\n'`. That \n is a line break character. That would confuse your logic right there.

Answer (score 1):

So it is a bit confusing what you are trying to do but you should check n after the user has inputed a value for n. not at the end.

You may want to also catch the exception where file cannot be found I think this is what you need:

```
fileName = raw_input("Enter the filename: ")
n = input("Enter the line you want to look: ")
if n == 0:
    print "There is no 0 line"
    sys.exit();

try:
    f = open(fileName,'r')
except IOError:
    print "Could not find file"
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: @Zfrd If this answered your question could you be so kind as to accept it as the correct answer. Thank you